Besides 42167 (Mack garbage truck) are there any other sets with bags NOT made out of the normal clear plastic?
The Mack garbage truck set (42167) has a recycling/green theme going on.
Probably as a nod to that theme, the 4 bags containing the pieces are made (mostly) from paper in stead of the regular clear plastic.
The smaller bags (7 in total) inside the larger ones are made from paper too.
Please note I say mostly above. The paper still has a thin inner lining/coating that feels like plastic. It makes the smaller bags hard to tear open. The big ones have a perforation on one side that serves as a tear-off strip.
Are there more sets (with bags of pieces) that have a different material than the regular clear plastic?
With "regular clear plastic" I mean both the soft poly-ethylene like material of unmarked bags and the more crispy cellophane like material of the numbered bags.

It's not a theme for that set, they want to switch generally to those bags.

@Henriksupportsthecommunity So they are gradually phasing them in? Would make future bag-id questions a real nuisance. You can't see the content without opening them, which means ripping them apart...

That's my understanding, and I agree it will make bags harder to identify, I don't think our troubles are a factor in TLG's decitions (and I think it will mean that a log of bags are re-packaged, making identification harder).

@Henriksupportsthecommunity I agree.

TLG is working towards making all its packaging sustainable by the end of 2025. Paper bags have been trialed since 2021. Here's an excerpt from a press release from 2020:

The company will begin to phase out single-use plastic bags used in
LEGO boxes to package the loose bricks. This is part of its ambition
to make all its packaging sustainable by the end of 2025. From 2021,
Forest Stewardship Council-certified recyclable paper bags will be
trialled in boxes.
Christiansen said: “We have received many letters from children about
the environment asking us to remove single-use plastic packaging. We
have been exploring alternatives for some time and the passion and
ideas from children inspired us to begin to make the change.”
Moving away from the existing packaging is not a simple task and will
take time as new material must be durable, light weight and enhance
the building experience.

Paper bags are present in other sets, and the expectation is that they will continue to be used in more and more sets going forward.

From personal experience I can confirm that the 42179 Planet Earth and Moon in Orbit also came with opaque paper bags, and the numbered outer bags contained smaller ones inside them for the tiny pieces.

Interresting... In my case the big bags had a black print depicting various Technic bricks and the small ones were plain. Was that the same in your set?
